# sql query for fifo inventory

Tags: sql, sql-server, fifo

I'm having trouble with a simple problem for fifo sql query (to calculate profit for each sales day).

There are two tables Production and Invoice. For each day of sales, I have to output total sales profit by using FIFO method.

Example, for second day profit , I have to use leftover item from previous day with their respecting price.

Here is the tables and desired output result

```
CREATE TABLE Production
(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    Productid varchar(10),
    pdate date,
    Qty int,
    Price decimal(18, 2),
);

INSERT INTO Production (Productid,pDate, Qty ,Price) VALUES ('PD1', '01/01/2017', 8, 200);
INSERT INTO Production (Productid,pDate ,Qty ,Price) VALUES ('PD2', '02/01/2017', 14, 300);
INSERT INTO Production (Productid,pDate ,Qty ,Price) VALUES ('PD3', '03/01/2017', 15, 150);

CREATE TABLE Sales
(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    Sid varchar(10),
    sDate date,
    Productid varchar(10),
    Qty int,
);

INSERT INTO Sales (Sid,sDate ,Productid ,Qty) VALUES ('S001', '04/01/2017', 'PD1', 5);
INSERT INTO Sales (Sid,sDate ,Productid ,Qty) VALUES ('S002', '05/01/2019', 'PD2', 4);
INSERT INTO Sales (Sid,sDate ,Productid ,Qty) VALUES ('S003', '06/01/2019', 'PD3', 6);
```

Manual calculation for leftover formula for each day
( existing - sales qty ) + purchase qty = leftover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple check on `sales.qty < purchase.qty` won't work. Since even if you have `sales.qty < purchase.qty` but have leftovers from last day then you will be using those leftovers first.
You should use try this:

```
   with cte as(
select s.id,s.Sid,sDate,s.Productid,s.qty AS Qty,s.qty as saleqty,p.qty as productqty,p.price
  ,sum(p.qty-s.qty) over (order by sdate) as leftover
  from purchase P
inner join sales S
on p.productid=s.productid
and p.pdate=s.sdate
)
select id, Sid,sDate,Productid,Qty,
case when lag(leftover) over (order by sdate)>0 then lag(leftover *price) over( order by sdate)
+( saleqty-lag(leftover) over (order by sdate)) * price
else saleqty * price end as profit
from cte;
```

Comment: My left over manual calculation is (existing qty - sales qty) + purchase qty = leftover,
manual calculation for Profit for this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cca518e782b796641d938dd57a97b42f 
will become like this , first day 5*100 , then (5*100)+(8*150) = 1700, then last one is (4*150)+(16*95) = 2120

Comment: Wow, it really works. Thank you very much Mr. Shikhar Arora.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this would help.

```
SELECT 
     s.sid,
     s.sdate,
     p.productid,
     s.qty,
     CASE 
        WHEN s.qty <= p.qty 
            THEN s.qty*p.price 
        ELSE p.qty*p.price + (s.qty-p.qty) * (SELECT price FROM purchase WHERE pdate IN (SELECT MAX(pdate) FROM purchase WHERE pdate < s.sdate))
     END  AS PROFIT
 FROM purchase p
 JOIN sales s 
   ON p.productid = s.productid
      AND p.pdate = s.sdate
```

Comment: but that WHEN clause conditions doesn't work when purchased Qty and sales Qty changed.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=604f09062b2c9cc3af9f53c717dd11bd

End profit should be 500, 1700, 2175